# Is it possible to chat with other players via the PS4 Remote Play app?

Tags: ps4, ps-remote-play

Recently Sony has released the DS4 wireless adapter to enable "almost" all functionality of the PS4 joypad on PCs. I said almost because the only feature that was left out is the ability to use the microphone in order to live-chat to other players in videogames. Although on windows PCs it is possible to fully see that the microphone connected to the DS4 joypad is functioning correctly, the official app doesn't allow you to use the mic as it is constantly muted.

Thus, I was wondering: is there any way to get the audio being registered from the DS4 controller to the ps4 as when the joypad is connected to the ps4 it works perfectly (either the joypad is connected wirelessly or through the usb cable)?

Answer (score 1):

At present Remote Play for PC/Mac does not support microphone use through the DS4 or PC/Mac audio inputs. However, if connected directly to your PC/Mac output you can still hear other Party members.

This according to this page: https://www.playstation.com/en-ae/get-help/help-library/apps---features/remote-play/ps4--remote-play-for-pc-and-mac/